# Primefaces maven how to build snapshot version?

Tags: maven, build, primefaces, snapshot

Do I need to change the version in pom.xml? For example,

```
 11.0.0.snapshot20220708
```

Is there command line options for building a snapshot version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I do this everyday with 12.0.0-SNAPSHOT in the pom.xml run this maven command.

`mvn clean install` but it must be `-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Is -SNAPSHOT a command line option? or I have to change version in pom.xml?

Comment: I always just change it in pom.xml to 12.0.0-SNAPSHOT